# List all form element with their properties

Tags: jquery

i want to list all form elements with their properties  with jquery , i write this code , it works for element index 0 in form , but for other elements page will refresh and ... !
here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form#registerForm").submit(function(){
        var allInputs = $("form#registerForm :input");
        $.each(allInputs, function(index, field) { 
            $("#res").append(index + " :: " + field + "<br />");
            $.each(field, function(pIndex, pValue) { 
                $("#res").append(pIndex + " :: " + pValue + "<br />");
            });
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that an error occurs in your method, causing the `return false` statement to never be reached.

To avoid such problems, use `event.preventDefault()` at the beginning of your `submit` handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form#registerForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).find(":input").each(function(index, field) { 
            $("#res").append(index + " :: " + field + "<br />");
            // What do you expect below..?
            $.each(field, function(pIndex, pValue) { 
                $("#res").append(pIndex + " :: " + pValue + "<br />");
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @nader My answer is still jQuery. You haven't provided a demo or your expectations, so no-one knows what's wrong with your code. If it's "not working", can you phrase a clearer question?

Comment: thanks for your answer , but this work only for the first element in form , i want to list all of them

Comment: @nader Your code didn't work, because an error is thrown when a certain property is read. Use `try-catch` to ignore errors: http://jsfiddle.net/nwWsE/4/. Also, for very large `append()` calls, it is more efficient to concatenate the output in one string, then using `.append()` in the end.